# I can't connect my raspberry pi with my laptop

Tags: raspberry-pi3, putty, vnc, vnc-viewer

I had a raspberry pi I want to connect to my laptop and use the raspberry pi directedly from my laptop, I try PuTTY and VNC following tutorial on youtube, but can't get them to connect; in PuTTY had connection refused, as for VNC connected with the pi.

Comment: Hi @Rookies DJ, I've tried to connect raspberry pi model b+ to my macbook and it works. Are you using a macbook?

Comment: You have to enable ssh on the raspberry pi first!

Comment: No I'm using window, I check on Pi that ssh is enable, by the ways; thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments you need to enable SSH on your pi.
If you have a screen you can use to view the desktop, it's pretty easy, enter:
`sudo raspi-config` (in to a terminal) navigate to interfacing options and you will be able to enable both SSH and VNC.

If you do not have a monitor or any way to view the desktop of your pi, you will have to do it the hard way by copying a file to your pi SD card to enable SSH, here is a link to a tutorial on how it works [Enabling SSH on pi without screen](https://hackernoon.com/raspberry-pi-headless-install-462ccabd75d0)

Honestly, though, the first option is the best, easiest and most foolproof.